# How could I reset the last download location in Google Chrome without downloading another file?

Tags: google-chrome

While the `Ask where to save each file before downloading` feature is turned on.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Chrome address bar, type:

```
chrome://settings/search#download
```

At the bottom you should see the location to specify where downloads should go. Click the "Change" button.